# Getting IEnumerable<Microsof.Exchange.WebService.Data.ItemId> from FindItems using EWS API

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm writing a C# app to go through some monitoring mailboxes and clear out emails that are older than a specified period (e.g. 6 months).

Previously I was going to get the items, then in a `foreach` block, delete each one in turn. Looking for a solution to another issue, I stumbled upon using `DeleteItems`. This expects a `System.Collection.Generic.IENumerable<Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemId>` but in the code below, `FindItems` returns a `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collecion<Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item>`.

How would I convert or get the correct type to pass to DeleteItems?

```
ExtendedPropertyDefinition allFoldersType = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(13825, MapiPropertyType.Integer);

FolderId rootFolderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Root);
FolderView folderView = new FolderView(1000);
folderView.Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep;

SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection searchFilterCollection = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And);
searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(allFoldersType, "2"));
searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName, "allitems"));

FindFoldersResults findFoldersResults = exchangeService.FindFolders(rootFolderId, searchFilterCollection, folderView);

Folder allItemsFolder = findFoldersResults.Folders[0];

searchFilterCollection = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And);
searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.IsLessThanOrEqualTo(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6)));
searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(ItemSchema.ItemClass, "IPM.Note"));

var findItems = allItemsFolder.FindItems(searchFilterCollection, new ItemView(100));
var items = findItems.Items;

exchangeService.DeleteItems(findItems, DeleteMode.HardDelete, SendCancellationsMode.SendToNone, AffectedTaskOccurrence.SpecifiedOccurrenceOnly);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `Item` has an `Id` property of type `ItemId`, it can be accessed using linq:

```
var findItems = allItemsFolder.FindItems(searchFilterCollection, new ItemView(100));
var itemIds = findItems.Items.Select(item => item.Id);

exchangeService.DeleteItems(itemIds, DeleteMode.HardDelete, SendCancellationsMode.SendToNone, AffectedTaskOccurrence.SpecifiedOccurrenceOnly);
```

Item Docs: [microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item?view=exchange-ews-api)

Item Id Docs: [Microsoft_Exchange_WebServices_Data_Item_Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item.id?view=exchange-ews-api#Microsoft_Exchange_WebServices_Data_Item_Id)